# Height 100% inside min-height px

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make footer which has min-height: 70px and inside footer theres an address, social media, logo, etc.

The question is why I can't make **height** for address, social media, logo, etc. **100%** ???

Simple CSS

```
div.min {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
div.in {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And simple HTML

```
<div class="min">
    <div class="in">
    </div>
</div>
```

If I **change the min-height into height its working**, can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: When using percentage heights, the parent must have the `height` property.

Comment: If min-height is set to 100, then it gives it 100% of parent container whatever that may be. When you set `.in` to 100% it takes 100% of it's parent, in this case, `.min` and `.min` takes 100% from the height of its parent

Comment: You can set the height of the parent to 1 px and keep the min-height the same.

Comment: Ah I see, so we can't assume min-height is height with flexibility?, and sorry if this question duplicate since I couldn't find the problem with min-height in pixel @Michael_B

Comment: An in-flow element with a percentage height needs a height reference from the parent. Browsers have traditionally used the `height` property for such reference. `min-height` and `max-height` won't work. More details in the duplicates.